# SVN not ignoring files

Tags: svn, version-control, svnignore

I want a repository to completely ignore some certain files - the equivalent of add those files to .gitignore in a git system. I tried:

```
svn propset svn:ignore *.aux" .
```

to ignore all `.aux` files. However, after doing that and a successful `svn commit`, `svn status` still shows:

```
?       something.aux
!       somethingelse.aux
```

is there an even stronger way to tell it to ignore these files so they don't show up in lists like this?

Comment: See this: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html.

Comment: I assume you have a typo in "svn propset" command you've mentioned. There should not be '"' (quotes sign).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually a common question and I strongly advise you to consider the SVNBook chapter ["Ignoring Unversioned Items"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html) that covers it.

See the important excerpt from the SVNBook which explains the behavior:

> **Subversion's support for ignorable file patterns extends only to the
>   one-time process of adding unversioned files and directories to
>   version control**. Once an object is under Subversion's control, the
>   ignore pattern mechanisms no longer apply to it. In other words, don't
>   expect Subversion to avoid committing changes you've made to a
>   versioned file simply because that file's name matches an ignore
>   pattern—Subversion always notices all of its versioned objects.

According to the `svn status` output, your working copy contains [one unversioned item (the one with the **'?'** sign) and one missing item (the one with the **'!'** sign)](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html).

```
?       something.aux
!       somethingelse.aux
```

So you've manually removed (i.e. through Windows Explorer, but not via SVN client) the `somethingelse.aux` and it now has 'missing' status. The other file `something.aux` is still unversioned and is **not** ignored.

If you didn't mistype the `svn propset` command, committed the property change and the file still has unversioned status you may find this excerpt helpful:

> the patterns found in the svn:ignore property apply only to the
>   directory on which that property is set, and not to any of its
>   subdirectories.

Additionally you can check the `svn:ignore` property by issuing the [`svn propget`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.propget.html) command.